# Newton's first law, unless + past participle

Tags: conjunctions, conditional-constructions, ellipsis

I was reading Newton's first law:

> An object at rest stays at rest and an object in motion stays in
>   motion with the same speed and in the same direction unless acted upon
>   by an unbalanced force.

In the part:

> unless acted upon by an unbalanced force.

The meaning is clear but I had never seen this construction:

```
unless + verb (pp)
```

Is this construction correct?

Also if you can explain all the grammar of this last part (`unless....`) I would appreciate it so much

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217231/newtons-first-law-unless-past-participle/217234?noredirect=1#comment462692_217234) on English Language & Usage, if you don't want to click the link here is the answer:

**Jlcgd's answer:**

```
In this context, the phrase
```

> unless acted upon by an unbalanced force.

```
is a short-hand notation for
```

> unless [the object is] acted upon by an unbalanced force.

```
 You will see a similar type of shortened speech in an American legal context. They do it for the sake of brevity.
```